# Hello, how to implement text typing effect like this website https://gm.graphics/

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

any library or any custom code that helps to do that tell us. I tried some libraries but that not work properly.

Comment: What's not working? Please show your efforts and describe the parts you're stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to achieve this using React

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [typewriter_text, setTypeWriterText] = useState("");
    const text_to_type = "Hello there adventurer~";
    let typewriter_timer;

    const typingAnimation = (i = 0) => {
        if (i < text_to_type.length) {
            setTypeWriterText(text_to_type.substring(0, i + 1));
            typewriter_timer = setTimeout(() => typingAnimation(i + 1), 100);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        typingAnimation();

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(typewriter_timer);
        };
    }, []);

    return <div>{typewriter_text}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Basically the idea is to add the text one by one with a `setTimeout` function acting as a delay.

```
const typingAnimation = (i = 0) => {
        if (i < text_to_type.length) {
            setTypeWriterText(text_to_type.substring(0, i + 1));
            typewriter_timer = setTimeout(() => typingAnimation(i + 1), 100);
        }
    };
```

The function above will add the letters in the text to type one. It calls it self again after a delay. `i` here is like an index that keep tracks of what the previous letter is.